# module 'moviepy' has no attribute 'VideoFileClip'

Tags: python, audio, wav, webm

I want covert .webm file to .wav file. but I getting module ['moviepy' has no attribute 'VideoFileClip'].I have read the docs for MoviePy but cannot find out why this is happening. My Python program runs perfectly from within the IDE (PyCharm) but after compiling, I am getting the MoviePy error. I have used the recommended from moviepy.editor import * I also used the from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

heres the code

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(file)
audio = clip.audio.write_audiofile(file + ".wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import `moviepy.editor` module

```
clip = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(file)
```